# Double slashes after base url in magento admin panel

Tags: url, magento-1.9

I have a new installation of magento 1.9 . After login as admin , the new admin url adds double slashes after base url before index.php as shown below

http://magento:10088//index.php/admin/index/index/key/...

How can I fix this double slashes

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

The purpose is to remove double (or more) slashes from URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing slash from the base url, you need to add below code in .htaccess under  tag.

### Remove for trailing slash

```
RewriteCond %{request_method} ^GET$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/downloader.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ %1 [L,R=301]
```